# What C++14 rule prohibits constexpr functions from making assignments to data members?

Tags: c++, constexpr, c++14

My understanding is that this (nonsensical) code is not valid C++14:

```
class Point  {
public:
  constexpr double setX(double newX) { return x = newX; }
private:
  double x;
};
```

I'm trying to figure out what part of the (still officially draft) C++14 Standard disallows it. The restrictions on constexpr functions are listed in 7.1.5/2. (Sorry for the mangled formatting. I can't figure out how to beat markdown into making it look right.)

> The definition of a constexpr function shall satisfy the following
>   constraints:
>
> - it shall not be virtual (10.3);
> - its return type shall be a literal type;
> - each of its parameter types shall be a literal type;
> - its function-body shall be = delete, = default, or a  compound-statement that does not contain
>
>   - an asm-definition,
>   - a goto statement,
>   - a try-block, or
>   - a definition of a variable of non-literal type or of static or thread storage duration or for which no initialization is performed.

There's nothing there that prohibits assignments to data members. There is such a prohibition in 5.19/2 (bullet 15) (again with mangled formatting, sorry):

> A conditional-expression e is a core constant expression unless the
>   evaluation of e, following the rules of the abstract machine (1.9),
>   would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>   [...]
>   modification of an object (5.17, 5.2.6, 5.3.2) unless it is applied to a non-volatile lvalue of literal type
>   that refers to a non-volatile object whose lifetime began within the evaluation of e;

But I don't see how 5.19 applies to 7.1.5. Can somebody clarify?

Comment: Why do you think it's not legal C++14?

Comment: @DietrichEpp `void` is a literal type. OTOH, `Point` is not a literal type without a `constexpr` constructor.

Comment: @T.C. It looks like I misinterpreted error messages from g++ and Clang. Apparently they were applying the C++11 rule that constexpr member functions are implicitly const. With the proper configuration, it looks like Clang 3.2 is happy, and that suggests that the code is valid (with the non-void return type).

Answer (score 5):

It is valid C++14. You can modify members of a literal class type as long as the lifetime of the object is contained within the evaluation of the constant expression.

The use of `Point` in a constant expression is controversial ([CWG DR 1452](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1452)), but it is allowed by current implementations. It would be a literal class except that it is not aggregate (§3.9.1/10) because it has a private field (§8.5.1/1). However its construction does not invoke its non-constexpr constructor because it is trivially-constructible. Anyway, this issue is fixed by adding a declaration `constexpr Point() = default;`.

§5.19 restricts what can be evaluated in a constant expression. One restriction is that only `constexpr` functions may be entered. §7.1.5 specifies what functions may be marked `constexpr`, but note that `constexpr` functions may contain (in a conditional statement) things that cannot be evaluated in a constant expression.

See the proposal papers, [second](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3652.html) and [first](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3597.html) drafts.

Comment: I don't think `Point` is a literal type, though. The implicit default constructor can't be `constexpr` because it would leave `x` uninitialized, and it's not an aggregate either.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the defaulted default constructor of `Point` is `constexpr`. It's trivial, so (by the weird value-initialization rules) it's *not called* in an expression of the form `Point()`, and in particular `Point().setX(1.0)` would be a constant expression. (See also http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1452)

Answer (score 3):

If you add an in-class initializer to `x`, e.g. `{}`, then it compiles on Clang 3.4 in `-std=c++1y` mode:

```
class Point  {
public:
  constexpr double setX(double newX) { return x = newX; }
  constexpr double getX() const { return x; }
private:
  double x {}; // without init: "error: constexpr function never produces a constant expression [-Winvalid-constexpr]"
};

constexpr Point f()
{
    Point p;
    p.setX(1.0);
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    auto constexpr p = f();        
    static_assert(p.getX() == 1.0, "");
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/655c408b7884a7ba).

If you have other constructors for `Point`, you need to add `constexpr Point() = default;` in order for it to work.