# In C++14 can a constexpr member change a data member?

Tags: c++, constants, c++14, member, constexpr

In C++14, since `constexpr` are not implicitly `const` anymore, can a `constexpr` member function modify a data member of a class:

```
struct myclass
{
    int member;
    constexpr myclass(int input): member(input) {}
    constexpr void f() {member = 42;} // Is it allowed?
};
```

Comment: you could have easily [tried this yourself](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d31080d797cd9dd3)...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What C++14 rule prohibits constexpr functions from making assignments to data members?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25152301/what-c14-rule-prohibits-constexpr-functions-from-making-assignments-to-data-me)

Comment: [yet another duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23647492/819272)

Comment: @TemplateRex I dislike *try it for yourself* comments, there are plenty of cases where trying it out may appear to work but the program is still wrong. For constexpr we have many cases that are ill-formed NDR for example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22176777/1708801) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32009602/1708801)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I see your point, but in this case, the question was pretty much not researched at all, there are a couple of dupes. The OP, while sometimes asking really interesting stuff, also has a tendency to quick-fire questions without doing the leg work. Also note that the 2 Q&As you gave, both had compilable code examples...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they are, I believe this change started with [proposal N3598: constexpr member functions and implicit const](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3598.html) and eventually became part of [N3652: Relaxing constraints on constexpr functions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3652.html) which changed section `7.1.5` paragraph `3` what is allowed in the function body from a white-list:

> its function-body shall be = delete, = default, or a
>   compound-statement that contains only
>
> - null statements,
> - static_assert-declarations
> - typedef declarations and alias-declarations that do not define classes or enumerations,
> - using-declarations,
> - using-directives,
> - and exactly one return statement;

to a black-list:

> its function-body shall be = delete, = default, or a compound-statement that does not contain
>
> - an asm-definition,
> - a goto statement,
> - a try-block, or
> - a definition of a variable of non-literal type or of static or thread storage duration or for which
>     no initialization is performed.

and also added the following notes to section `C.3.3` Clause 7: declarations:

> Change: constexpr non-static member functions are not implicitly const
>   member functions.
>
> Rationale: Necessary to allow constexpr member functions to mutate the
>   object.
>
> Effect on original feature: Valid C++ 2011 code may fail to compile in
>   this International Standard. For example, the following code is valid
>   in C++ 2011 but invalid in this International Standard because it
>   declares the same member function twice with different return types:
>
> ```
> struct S {
>  constexpr const int &f();
>  int &f();
> };
> ```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, yes. The restrictions are, from [dcl.constexpr]:

> The definition of a `constexpr` function shall satisfy the following constraints:
> — it shall not be virtual (10.3);
> — its return type shall be a literal type;
> — each of its parameter types shall be a literal type;
> — its *function-body* shall be `= delete`, `= default`, or a *compound-statement* that does not contain
>
> - an *asm-definition*,
> - a `goto` statement,
> - a *try-block*, or
> - a definition of a variable of non-literal type or of static or thread storage duration or for which
>   no initialization is performed.

The function meets all those requirements.